# C# claims my SQLite table doesn't exist but it does

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

I'm trying to read a table I created with DB Browser for SQLite, but there's a runtime error claiming the database doesn't have the table. But it does! I created it and I can see it in DB Browser.

Here's the code:

```
    private void PopulateGridCustomers()
    {
        String conString = Properties.Resources.database;
        var con = new SqliteConnection(conString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            Console.WriteLine(con.State);
            SqliteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Clientes";
            using (SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conString))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                gridCustomers.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```

And a picture showing the table exists indeed:

[image]

What could be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Thanks

P.S.: Please cut me some slack, I'm not a professional developer. I code for myself.

Update: Here's the actual error message:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: 'The specified table does not exist. 
[ Clientes ]'
```

UPDATE 2:

Here's the path of the database:

```
Data Source=C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\Documentos\SBM\Database\SBMTeste.db;
```

As you can see, it is the very same that shows in DB Browser window. The error I first described occurs if I omit the ".db". If I put the file extension in the string, the following error is thrown:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: 'The database file may be corrupted. 
Run the repair utility to check the database file. 
[ Database name = C:\Users\charl\OneDrive\Documentos\SBM\Database\SBMTeste.db ]'
```

UPDATE 3:

Here's the CREATE statement of the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Clientes" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "nome"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "telefone1" TEXT,
    "telefone2" TEXT,
    "email" TEXT,
    "endereço"  TEXT,
    "bairro"    TEXT,
    "cidade"    TEXT,
    "data_nascimento"   TEXT,
    "data_cadastro" TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
    UNIQUE("nome","data_nascimento")
)
```

Comment: *the compiler throws an error claiming the database doesn't have the table* There is something wrong with that description. I wouldn't normally expect table existence to be checked at compile time. Can you cut and paste the actual error message, instead of paraphrasing?

Comment: Please include the error as I seriously doubt the compiler would complain that the table is missing.

Comment: Maybe the program is looking at a different copy of the database than your DB browser.

Comment: Verify that the database that you see in DB Browser for SQLite is the same as the one your app accesses.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. The question is updated showing the error message.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just FYI that's a runtime exception, not a compiler error. Please ensure you understand the difference - it can often be significant. Also next time please paste the error details as text, not pictures.

Comment: Anyway, again it strongly suggests that the C# program is not looking at the same database as your DB browser. Double-check the setup.

Comment: Also post the CREATE statement of the table as it is stored in DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: Updated with the asked clarifications.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and forgive for not giving enough info sou you could find the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server CE is not SQLite.

This is an extract of my code using SQLite:

```
public Equity SearchEquityByEpic(string epic)
{
    string query = string.Format("SELECT * from " + Tables.ASSETS_TABLE + " WHERE epic='{0}'", epic);
    Log(query);

    var command = _connection.CreateCommand(query);
    var equities = command.ExecuteQuery<Equity>();

    if (equities.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    Equity ret = equities.First();

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is I messed up when trying to install the packages needed for my application to work with the SQlite database. I endend up installing a lot of unnecessary things and missing using `System.Data.SQLite`. That way my application was not being able to recognize the .db file hence the "corrupted file" message described in my 3rd update.

Comment: @Enigmativity is there any rule against apologies and gratefulness?

Comment: We don't put a lot of society niceties in our questions and answers on this site. If you want to say thanks then do so in a comment. If you didn't provide enough information then, by all means, add the information to your question.

Comment: It's pointless to add any information to the question now that it has been settled already,

Comment: No, it's not. This site's purpose is to provide a set of quality questions and answers ***for future readers***. It's not specifically for the person who asked the question. We all should strive to improve the quality of the site.